# How to activate latm encoding with avformatcontext

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, aac

I'm trying to set up an [rtp encoder](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/rtpenc_8h-source.html) with [acc latm support](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/latmenc_8c_source.html), but whatever I try I can't seem to get it to work:

```
AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("aac");
AVCodecContext *codecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

AVFormatContext *formatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatCtx, NULL, "rtp", NULL);
av_opt_set(m_formatCtx, "rtpflags", "+latm",0 );
formatCtx->flags |= (AVFMT_FLAG_MP4A_LATM | AVFMT_FLAG_BITEXACT);

AVStream *avStream = avformat_new_stream(formatCtx, codec);
avStream->codec = codecCtx;
```

Am I using the wrong codec? I ran `ffmpeg -codecs | grep latm` to find the only latm codec to be for decoding, so latm encoding is only available as an output format. I found the flags from [rtpenc_chain source](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/rtpenc__chain_8c_source.html).

My output is always 'MPEG4-GENERIC' while I'm aiming for 'MP4A-LATM'.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the rtp flag in the header, no need to edit avcontext flags. So:

```
AVDictionary *optionsDict = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&optionsDict, "rtpflags", "latm",0 );
avformat_write_header(formatCtx,&optionsDict) != 0);
```